# How to check if coordinates are left or right of coordinates with given degrees in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coordinate-systems

The question title might be a  little confusing, imagine this:

[image]

In this diagram, I know the postions of points a and b (their x and y values) - the origin though is in the top left corner, so `yb` for instance is somewhat at 137 and `ya` 81. Also, I know the degree value of the angle `<) a` which defines how much the lighter rectangle is rotated (I also know how much the other one is rotated, if that is of use).

So, I want to check if point `a` is left or right of an imaginary line (axis, the pink line) of point b. How would you do that? I know it's simply maths probably but I'm lost.

```
var isleft = function(xb,yb, xa, ya, degree) {
    if the point at xa, ya is left from the line starting at point xb, yb using d degrees return true;

};
```

I guess I would have to use a simple linear function to do this, but I dont know how to deal with the degrees, calculate the respective coordinates on that line for a given y value, so help is appreciated.

Comment: I didnt say anything about any vector, thats all the values I am provided

Comment: Question is unclear... Where is `degree` on your picture?

Comment: with degree I mean the degree the light grey rectangle is rotated, I will update the image

Comment: diagram updated. angle a says how much rectangle 2 is rotated, i dont know if that is of interest. i also know the angle of how much rectangle 1 is rotated, but I thought knowing the points is enough

Comment: You need to find the angle between two vectors with origin `(yb, xb)`, one up the side of the rectangle and the other through `(ya, xa)`. The information you have provided now is sufficient. No doubt there are many solutions, but some will be more efficient than others. Incidentally, why are the coordinates ordered `y, x`? Cartesian coordinates are typically they are ordered `x, y`.

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the bearing from point *b* to point *a* and if it's less than the angle *a* (the bearing along the side of the rectangle) then the point is "left", otherwise it's "right". The following function returns the bearing from *b* to *a*, but using coordinate order `(x, y)`. The coordinate direction is per the screen, i.e. +x to the right and +y downward (a normal cartesian system would be +y up):

```
// Long version
function calcAngle(a, b) {
  var PI = Math.PI;
  var points
  var dx = b[0] - a[0];
  var dy = a[1] - b[1];
  var beta = Math.atan(dx / dy);

  // 1st quadrant
  if (dx >= 0 && dy >=0) return beta;

  // 2nd quadrant
  if (dx >= 0 && dy < 0) return PI + beta;

  // 3rd quadrant
  if (dx < 0 && dy < 0)  return PI + beta;

  // 4th quadrant
  if (dx < 0 && dy >= 0) return 2*PI + beta
}
```

In the above, *a* and *b* are coordinate pairs in `(x, y)` order, where *a* is point *b* in the diagram and *b* is point *a* in the diagram. Some tests:

```
// Convert radians to degrees
function rad2deg(rad) {return rad * 180 / Math.PI}

var pair, points = [
  // 1st quadrant
  [[10, 30], [12, 15]],  //   7.6 deg
  [[10, 30], [12, 30]],  //  90.0 deg
  // 2nd quadrant
  [[10, 30], [20, 31]],  //  95.7 deg
  [[10, 30], [10, 40]],  // 180.0 deg
  // 3rd quadrant
  [[10, 30], [ 1, 31]],  // 263.7 deg
  [[10, 30], [ 5, 30]],  // 270.0 deg
  // 4th quadrant
  [[10, 30], [ 5, 5]],   // 348.7 deg
  [[10, 30], [10, 5]]    //   0.0 deg
];

for (var i=0, iLen=points.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  pair = points[i];
  console.log(pair[0] + ',' + pair[1] + ' : ' + rad2deg(calcAngle(pair[0], pair[1])));
}
```

The function can be more concise:

```
function calcAngle(a, b) {
  var PI = Math.PI;
  var dx = b[0] - a[0];
  var dy = a[1] - b[1];
  var beta = Math.atan(dx / dy);
  if (dy < 0) return PI + beta;
  if (dx < 0 && dy >= 0) return 2*PI + beta
  return beta;
}
```

To work out left or right, use the *calcAngle* function to work out the second bearing and compare it to the first. If it's less, it's to the left. If it's greater, it's to the right. That sense is always clockwise, which may not suit.

e.g. if *a* is 5° and the calculated angle is 355°, is that 350° to the right or 10° to the left? You may decide that if the difference it more than 180° to reverse the side (e.g. 181° to the right is seen as 179° to the left).

Comment: as it turns out, this method was not very accurate, or i used it wrongly. thanks anyways

Comment: I presume you mean using an angle and two points wasn't accurate. The mathematics are as accurate as ECMAScript maths can be.

Comment: i was looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2VXXP/6/ :) your code did not work, maybe i did something wrong

Comment: @Alex—because my code wasn't intended to find intersecting sides but the angle between two vectors given two points and an angle. No problem, kept some brain cells employed for a while. :-)